# In SSIS, can a VB Script Component be stored in the solution for easy re-use in packages?

Tags: ssis

Can an SSIS Script Component written in VB be saved in the SSIS solution so it's easy to re-use at multiple points in multiple packages?

For instance, I have a VB Script Component which removes double-spaces in a table column. Can I save the script in the Solution Explorer as a VB file or Class file, and then use it again in other Script Components at another point in the control flow? Or perhaps have it appear in the SSIS Toolbox as a custom component?

Comment: I have many tools like this.  For those I just create an SSIS package (or maybe solution) to hold all this stuff for me.  Then I just open the SSIS package, copy the object/script task and paste it into the new package I am working on.  As long as the script task was written well you wont even have to edit it when you paste it to new package (as long as you use all the same variables)

Comment: But what if I need to edit the code? Then I need to do so in many places. If the code was centralized, I only need to edit it once.